# Customize drag and drop in sortable jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using jquery ui connected list to drag and drop between 2 uls.Now drag and drop is working fine.
I want to write customised function for both the drops.How will I achieve this?

**I tried the following but it didn't worked for me(this executes for both drops)**

```
  $("#sortable1").sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        var id = ui.item.attr("id");
        alert(id);
        var val = ui.item.val();
        alert(val);
        var index = ui.item.index()+1;
        alert(index)
    }
});
```

**This doesn't execute for both drops**

```
 $("#sortable2").droppable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        var id = ui.item.attr("id");
        alert(id);
        var val = ui.item.val();
        alert(val);
        var index = ui.item.index() + 1;
        alert(index)

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you paste some HTML too?

Comment: @burflip I got it.. I shouldn't use update. Instead of that I have to use receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I need to use receive instead of update**

**For 1st ul drop function:**

```
$("#sortable1").droppable({
receive: function (event, ui) {
    debugger;
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
    alert(id);
    var val = ui.item.val();
    alert(val);
    var index = ui.item.index() + 1;
    alert(index)

}});
```

**For 2nd ul drop function:**

```
$("#sortable2").droppable({
receive: function (event, ui) {
    debugger;
    var id = ui.item.attr("id");
    alert(id);
    var val = ui.item.val();
    alert(val);
    var index = ui.item.index() + 1;
    alert(index)

}});
```